# TempTime in my ChangeTimeHandler returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to add two values, where i want to add startTimeHours + startTimeMinutes and endTimeMinutes + startTimeMinutes. The issue is when i debug the code, my tempTime returns [object Object].

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EERFm.jpg. As you can see from this picture, if i change (M), as I understand it, it overrides the other value?.

Here is my code.

```
 changeTimeHandler = (e) => {
        let tempTime = [...this.state.timeState];
        let tempState = [...this.state.bookings];
        let selectedTab = this.state.selectedTab;
        let name = e.target.name;
        let eValue = e.target.value;

        tempTime[name] = eValue;

        let startTime = tempTime.startTimeHours + ":" + tempTime.startTimeMinutes;
        let endTime = tempTime.endTimeHours + ":" + tempTime.endTimeMinutes;

        tempTime.startTime = startTime;
        tempTime.endTime = endTime;
        console.log("TempTime: " + tempTime);
        tempTime = checkPriceValue(name, tempTime, selectedTab, eValue);
        console.log("TempState: " + tempState);
        this.setState({ timeState: tempTime, bookings: tempState })

    };
```

I expect the value from 0-24 in startTimeHours or 00 or 30 in startTimeMinutes.

Comment: Can you show me code where you are assigning the timeState in state?

Comment: "The issue is when i debug the code, my tempTime returns [object Object]" - there is nothing wrong with that, as tempTime is Object. Try with console.log(tempTime.startTime)...

Comment: https://imgur.com/wJQdMXx This is here. @BalajiKondalrayal

Comment: tempTime is object only. It will return as [object Object]. print for tempTime.startTime as mentioned by @jare25

Comment: Thanks @BalajiKondalrayal. But problem is when i set the state for startTimeHours to 14 and then the value 30 to startTimeMinutes, it removes the state from startTimeHours or overrides it. I can't figure out why.